# What will happen if I don’t call NetworkStream.endRead in callback of BeginRead?

Tags: c#, .net-core, networkstream, .net-core-2.0

I’m trying to implement a timeout feature based on `NetworkStream` old Async methods.
Due to the fact that calling `EndRead` to a closed `NetworkStream` will throw an "ObjectDisposedException", I wonder if I can simply avoid to call `EndRead` instead of catching that exception as it is like an ugly hack.

Comment: I like the idea of an `ObjectDespisedException` [sic] :)
did you try it, and what happened? any code to go with your question?

Comment: @dlatikay Id be for ever throwing it

Comment: Thanks for this lol